# Regex filtering Discord URL Markdown for Discord Automod

Tags: regex, discord, markdown

I need regex to put into Discord's Automod feature that:

- matches any messages containing url markdown in the format `[...](...)` that would render as a link on the Discord client.
- does not match messages otherwise, including messages containing url markdown in the above format, but the Discord client does not render it.

The Discord client now renders url markdown such as

- `[test](https://stackoverflow.com/)`
- `[test](<http://google.com>)`
- `[test]( <http://google.com>)`
- 

```
[test
](

<http://google.com>

)
```

It does not render markdown such as

- `[test](/questions)`
- `[test](< http://google.com>)`
- `[test](< http://google.com >)`

---

In practice, if the above is not possible to achieve, I would rather err on the side of false positives, but I am not aware of the full differences between standard and Discord markdown, making it hard for me to do this.

The current regex I use

```
\[[\s\S]*\]\([\s\S]*https?:\/\/[\s\S]*\)
```

has many false positives which I would like to narrow down.

It catches any messages containing the above format, but also catches things like

```
Consider the clopen interval [0, 1).
We contrast this with (0, 1](I don't know why you wouldn't put a space
before the left parentheses...
but why not. Refer to https://google.com)
```

Comment: Can you add to your question a few examples of messages that you want to be filtered against the ones you don't want to be filtered please? It is not clear to me whether you want to filter that tagging pattern (`[...](...)`) with links or the tag pattern itself regardless of links on it

Comment: I only want to filter patterns that would render as a markdown link on the discord client. I've edited to clarify that point.

Comment: Then please explain how it works there and exactly from it you want to prevent. You know how it works in discord (we /me/ don't) we probably know how to build the regex. We need to sync our knowledge so we can help you better hence my suggestion of adding examples both ways :)

Comment: I have made it clear in the question that I do not know myself the full extent of how it works, hence why I ask it. I have included the `discord` tag to highlight this as best as possible. The question also already includes 2 examples - one which should be filtered, the other not.

Comment: Sounds good. I do not know either I'm just trying to help (the downvote was not me either). But right now your question is still unclear maybe because of the lack of knowledge. So please try to explain what is happening there with your current regex and what you would like to actually happen. Something like `this post has markdown [a](http://a.com) I want it filtered`; `this post is not a markdown [b](/commandB)`; `this post has a markdown with a site [x](www.x.com)` having what is rendering and what you like it to be rendering also helps. To define a regex we need to understand your rules..

Comment: exemplifying it with SO rules or discord rules doesn't make it clear to us that only know about regex.

Comment: Added an edit to improve

Comment: I've also had to edit the regex to catch newlines too - discovered they also render.

Comment: Much better. So your rule is that you want your regex to only filter valid /supposed/ markdown links that starts with `[`, some word(s)/line break in between, then `](` , a link without the `<>` and without spaces or a link within the `<>` but without spaces and the a `)` enter chars are allowed as long as the link is within `<>` rule

Comment: Something like this works for you? https://regex101.com/r/JCxU3g/1

Comment: Yes thank you, and could be an answer. But the main issue I have is - I do not have a full list of what works and what doesn't. That's the information I am looking for - from people knowledgeable about the discord client.

Comment: Added it as an answer for you! Glad that I could be of help!

Comment: Not sure if SO is the right place to check how that works though. The discord tag is mainly for their API stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:`\[[^]]+]\(\s*<?https?:\/\/.*?\s*>?\)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xx7ODH/1)

Answer (score 0):

Tha's awesome that we could get to an understanding. After our conversation on the comments here was the rules:

> Your rule is that you want your regex to only filter valid /supposed/ markdown links that starts with `[`, some word(s)/line break in between, then `](` , a link without the `<>` and without spaces or a link within the `<>` but without spaces and the a `)` enter chars are allowed as long as the link is within `<>` rule

Here is the Regex for this problem: `^\[[^\]]+\]\((?:\s*<?https?.+>?\s*)\)`

You can check it out here: https://regex101.com/r/JCxU3g/1